# Bitcoin-ABC creating a new wallet

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-cash, ecash

As I understand wallet information is on a file named "wallet.dat" I can backup/restore a wallet with that file. However what if I want a completely brand new wallet with no history. Is it enough to delete the "wallet.dat" file? would Bitcoin-ABC generate a new wallet after wallet.dat is deleted?

Comment: For future readers: the Bitcoin-ABC client is (confusingly) not a Bitcoin client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it enough to delete the "wallet.dat" file?

yes. make sure that bitcoin is not running

> would Bitcoin-ABC generate a new wallet after wallet.dat is deleted?

yes